# How can I find an LU factorisation of this $3 \times 3$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, lu-decomposition

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&-3\\-2&-4&8\\-3&-4&14\end{bmatrix}$$

This is what I found:

$$U=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&-3\\0&0&2\\0&0&8\end{bmatrix}$$

$$L=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\-2&1&0\\-3&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

There's something wrong about $U$, but I don't know what it is. Can someone help me please?

Comment: I just multiplied L and U together and the result isnt A.
It's hard to tell what you did wrong. Maybe you should show us more steps.

assuming you used the gaussian elimination, just do it again and check for mistakes.

Comment: Note that the leading $2\times2$ block of $A$ is singular; this precludes you finding an $LU$ decomposition without pivoting.

Answer (score 1):

You claim that something is wrong about $U$.

Assuming that $L$ is correct, then we will have $U=L^{-1}A$. Let's compute that.

```
octave:7> A = [1,2,-3; -2, -4, 8; -3, -4, 14]
A =

    1    2   -3
   -2   -4    8
   -3   -4   14

octave:8> L
L =

   1   0   0
  -2   1   0
  -3   1   1

octave:9> inv(L)*A
ans =

   1   2  -3
   0   0   2
   0   2   3
```

Yikes, $L$ is not correct.

Also,

```
octave:11> rank(A)
ans =  3
```

$U$ certainly can't have $(2,2)$-th entry being $0$.

The thing is there is no such decomposition for this matrix.

Suppose on the contrary that such decomposition exists.

Then we have

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} l_{11} & 0 & 0 \\ -2l_{11} & l_{22} & 0  \\ l_{31} & l_{32} & l_{33} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac1{l_{11}} & \frac2{l_{11}} & \frac{-3}{l_{11}} \\ 0 & u_{22} & u_{23}  \\ 0 & 0 & u_{33} \end{bmatrix} $$

From the $(2,2)$-th entry, we have $l_{22}u_{22}=0$, this would contradict the rank of matrix $A$.

You might like to consider an $LUP$ decomposition instead.